# Adding primes in a sequence in C++

Tags: c++

Consider a sequence of *n* positive integers, where *n* and the *n* numbers are entered on stdin, calculate the **sum** of those of the numbers which are prime.

How do I do that? I tried the following code but failed:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, i, j, numero = 0, primo = 0, soma = 0;
    cout << "Digite um numero: ";
    cin >> n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> numero;
        for (j = 1; j < n; j++)
        cout << " numero " << numero << endl;
        {
            if (numero %j == 0)
                primo ++;
                cout << "primo" << primo << endl;
        }
        if (primo == 2)
        {
            soma = soma + numero;
            cout << " numero " << numero << endl;
            cout << "soma" << soma << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << soma << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, you must define what "cousins" means in your question.  Then, give an example of input that isn't working, what the output IS, and what the output SHOULD BE.

Comment: Example: n=7; numero= 7 3 2 4 6 11 13; return soma=36, ie, 7+3+2+11+13=36

Comment: So why did 4 and 6 get excluded from the sum?  Because they're composite?  I can't tell from your question.

Comment: sum only prime number of sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very inefficient primality test.  But here's the problem:

> ```
>    for (j = 1; j < n; j++)
>    cout << " numero " << numero << endl;
>    {
>        if (numero %j == 0)
>            primo ++;
>            cout << "primo" << primo << endl;
>    }
> ```

First, the `cout` needs to be between the braces.  Currently the for loop only repeats the `cout`, not the block.

```
    for (j = 1; j < n; j++)
    {
       cout << " numero " << numero << endl;
       if (numero % j == 0)
          primo++;
       cout << "primo" << primo << endl;
    }
```

Next, factors of `numero` fall between `1` and `numero` **inclusive**, not `1` and `n` exclusive.  So the for loop exit condition is wrong.  It should be:

```
    for (j = 1; j <= numero; j++)
```

And, you must set the count of factors back to zero for each new number:

```
    for (primo = 0, j = 1; j <= numero; j++)
```

And now it works: http://ideone.com/FL4Ms